# Expected Number of empty slots when hashing

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable

I have n keys and a hash table of size n.

I am trying to figure out the expected number of empty slots.

I know the uniform Hashing Assumption states that every key is equally likely to go into any of the slots.

So far, I have come up with n keys each with equal chance of n slots, so n^2 possible combinations.

I am unsure of where to go from here, any points in the right direction would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: First, you should specify the type of hash table (multiple elements possible per slot? if not, which overflow treatment, ie. which strategy for determining alternative slots or something like that?) and the actual hash function (including data type of elements).

Comment: the problem is purely theory based and this is all I was given to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the number of possible combinations is not `n^2` but `n^n` since each of the `n` keys has `n` possibilities to land in a slot.

Next, due to all slots being symmetric, the expected number of empty slots `E = n * P`, where `P` is the probability that each *single* slot ends up empty. This is due to [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) which holds even when the random values are dependent.

Now, note that the probability `Q` that a single *key* does not land in this slot is `Q = (n - 1) / n`.

Since there are `n` keys, the probability `P` that no key lands in a fixed slot is `Q ^ n`.

Summing all that up, we have `E = n * ((n - 1) / n)^n`. The limit of `(n - 1/n)^n` is `1/e` ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Overview)), thus the expected number of empty slots is `n / e`.

Comment: I don't think you get to say "Next, due to all slots being symmetric, the expected number of empty slots E = n * P, where P is the probability that each single slot ends up empty."  This is true only if slots being empty are independent events. I can't see how they're independent.  One slot being empty clearly affects the probability that others are.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Gene: This is in fact true due to linearity of expectation. I clarified that in the answer. Thank you.